# Why is there no String.IsNumeric Function in C#

Tags: c#

I am just curious to know why the C# language team has not provided a IsNumeric function on the String object?. IsNumeric function would have been more proper on a String object that the Int32.TryParse Function.

Note: I am asking this question because I have found it difficult to explain this to a beginner and I don't like them cursing C# for this!

Update: Please, this question is not about how to Implement a IsNumeric function.

Comment: You can add it as extension method. :)

Comment: I am aware of extension method, but thats not the question here, but thanks anyways (-:

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The trouble with a method like that would be deciding what counts as "numeric". Should it allow decimals points, should it allow leading whitespace, should it have an upper bound for the number of digits?

Int32.TryParse answers the much more well-defined question of, "is this a valid string representation of an Int32?"

And of course, nothing is stopping you writing your own extension method, that decides if a string is numeric according to your own rules.

Comment: This hasn't stopped MS putting these methods on the Char data type.

Comment: That's because an individual char is either a numeric character or not so such a method makes sense

Answer (score 4):

Because there can be a ton of functions one can find useful and absolutely needed.

```
IsNumeric()
IsAlpha()
IsAlphaNumeric()
IsEmailAddress()
IsGuid()
...
```

And so on. Any individual can easily add a dozen more methods that he would consider as absolutely needed. A framework is only meant to stay generic and provide the basic tools for you to do your work and maybe to build your extra tools as needed.

That said, simply add your extension methods.

Comment: I feel IsNumeric function is something we have grown up with using in other languanges. And I feel this was absolutely needed, unless you want me to an expert who has deep knowledge of alternative functions in other Objects!

Answer (score 3):

There has to be a line somewhere, between the methods you put into a class and the operations that are better performed by other classes.

If there was a IsNumeric method, other people might ask for a IsValidPhoneNumber, IsValidEmailAddress, IsValidURI or even IsValidZipCodeInNewZealand methods... all of those might better be implemented in their own domain.

Comment: @Timbo If you go by the number of questions on IsNumeric function elsewhere on internet, you will understand why I asked this question. This is one common function which most of the developers would like to see in String object. For those who are coming from other languages/tools like VB6, would expect this to be available in String object!

Answer (score 3):

I think the logic behind `Int32.TryParse` is that the `Int32` class knows what is a valid 32-bit integer whereas the `String` class has no notion of what is a number at all.

The principle behind that is that an object can best check itself whether something can be treated as/converted to that specific object.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC there ist Char.IsDigit(char c);

Therefore I think that should work:

```
string _temp = "12341234";
bool _isNumeric = _temp.ToCharArray().All(x => Char.IsDigit(x));
```

And you could wrap that as an extension methods if you like.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for negative numbers, or any more sophisticated number format depending on the localization settings of the current user.

Comment: If you only allow natural numbers without leading or trailing space your expression makes sense. So it all depends what you define as "numeric".

Answer (score 0):

On a side-note: You can always implement your own:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static Boolean IsNumeric(this String s)
    {
        // your own definition goes here
    }
}
```