# Extension method to check whether a string is valid integer, double, bool etc

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create an extension method for `string` that says whether the string is a valid integer, double, bool or decimal. I'm not interested in **switch..case** and trying to use generics.

**Extension method**

```
public static bool Is<T>(this string s)
{
   ....
}
```

**Usage**

```
string s = "23";

if(s.Is<int>())
{
   Console.WriteLine("valid integer");
}
```

I couldn't able to succeed on implementing the extension method. I'm looking for some ideas/suggestions...

Comment: [Why is there no String.IsNumeric Function in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1508668/284240)

Comment: Take a look at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961656/generic-tryparse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work using the `Cast<>()` method:

```
    public static bool Is<T>(this string s)
    {
        bool success = true;
        try
        {
            s.Cast<T>();
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
    }
```

**EDIT**

Obviously this doesn't work every time, so I found another working version here:

```
public static bool Is<T>(this string input)
{
    try
    {
        TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromString(input);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961656/generic-tryparse).

Answer (score 3):

Use tryparse :

```
string someString = "42";
int result;
if(int.TryParse(someString, out result))
{
    // It's ok
     Console.WriteLine("ok: " + result);
}
else
{
    // it's not ok
    Console.WriteLine("Shame on you");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want;

```
public static bool Is<T>(this string s)
{

    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));

    try
    {   
        object val = converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(s);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementation example:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool Is<T>(this string s)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        {
            int tmp;
            return int.TryParse(s, out tmp);
        }

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(long))
        {
            long tmp;
            return long.TryParse(s, out tmp);
        }

        ...

        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var test1 = "test".Is<int>();
var test2 = "1".Is<int>();
var test3 = "12.45".Is<int>();
var test4 = "45645564".Is<long>();
```

Also do note that you should take some other parameters as input for the method, such as `IFormatProvider` to let the user specify the culture to use.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I'm not interested in multiple if statements and I think they make the code hard to maintain.

Comment: And they actually defeat the whole purpose of using generics

Answer (score -2):

I would use a try/catch

```
string a = "23";

try{

int b = a;

Console.WriteLine("valid integer");

}
catch
{
Console.WriteLine("invalid integer");
}
```